# Is there any difference between "Leave Open" and "Skip" in Close Votes Reviews?

Tags: support, review, reopen-closed

I often review Close Votes in my favorite SE site ever since I got the close vote privilege and I have seen both <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd> in the queues. What is the difference between both. From my understanding, marking it as "Leave Open" counts as a review, and "Skip" doesn't. Does marking as "Leave Open" add any reopen vote that negates a close vote or something like that?

Comment: *"Does marking as "Leave Open" add any reopen vote"* - leaving something open and reopening something are two different things, even in plain English. And yes, voting so works against the close votes.

Comment: @Tom Excellent, that's all I need to know. Care to add that as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: [From this answer](/a/139836/), if a post receives 3 Leave Open votes, it will remove from the close vote review queue.